# Linq to Sql where condition String NotSupported Exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to pull the password length from the ASP.net tables with the following linq to sql query

```
(from t1 in Aspnet_Users join t2 in Aspnet_Memberships
on t1.UserId equals t2.UserId
where decrypt(t2.Password).Length< 8 ||
  decrypt(t2.Password).Length>16
  select new { t1.UserName,
  t2.Email,
  Length=decrypt(t2.Password).Length})
```

but when I try to run this code. I am getting the following error.

NotSupportedException: Method 'System.String a(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Can you guys give me some idea to fix it?

Comment: Work around for this problem I choose is to convert  (Linq to Sql).ToList() and applied where on it. It took sometime though but worked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use C# method, in this case `decrypt`, in Linq to SQL. This works well with Linq to object but not with Linq to SQL as the whole linq query is converted to SQL query and then compiler fails to recognize your methods.

For this, you can convert this linq code to lambda expression, and make a `Func<>` delegate for your decrypt, and use this in your where clause.